# The second User Input stage is not showing up

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class AdamHmwk4 {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      int counter1;
      int counter2;
      int counter3;
      String answer = "";

      System.out.println("Welcome to Adam's skip-counting program!");
      System.out.println("Please input the number you would like to skip count by.");
      counter1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

      if (answer.equals(counter1)) {
         System.out.println("Please input the number you would like to start at.");
         counter2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

         if (answer.equals(counter2)) {
            System.out.println("Please input the number you would like to stop at.");
            counter3 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            if (answer.equals(counter3)) {
               System.out.println("This is skip counting by");
               System.out.println(counter1);
               System.out.println(",starting from");
               System.out.println(counter2);
               System.out.println("and ending at");
               System.out.println(counter3);

            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When I compile and run this code, the first part executes well, but when I input a number for it, the next user input part does not show. Please keep in mind that I am new to Java.

Comment: Consider fixing your code indentation so that we can actually read it. This will increase our chances of being able to understand it and then help you.

Comment: OK, if you won't fix it, I'll fix it for you, but please in the future put in the effort yourself. You'll get better answers quicker, and you'll get our respect.

Comment: `if (answer.equals(counter1)) {` this is wrong will give you alwasy `false`. `answer` is `String` and `counter1` is `int`

Answer (score 1):

Your if-statement(s) is never true. `answer` is a `String` variable, while `counter1` is an int.

```
if (answer.equals(counter1)) {
   ...
```

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> public boolean equals(Object anObject)
>
> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and **is a String object** that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.